# Other than redis-ha config, pretty much everything is same in stand-aloneinstall.yaml & high availability (install.yaml) files

Tags: devops, argocd, argo, gitops

In ArgoCD official GitHub repo, the only difference I can see is the configuration of Redis with high availability and I dont see any other differences.
How does this redis with high availability works in practical world? What are their use cases?

References:
HA:  argo-cd/manifests/ha/install.yaml at master · argoproj/argo-cd (github.com)
Stand-Alone:   argo-cd/manifests/install.yaml at master · argoproj/argo-cd (github.com)